# How can i open VB app in another computer?

Tags: vb.net

I am a begginer with visual basic. I made an app that contains pictures, 2 databases with sql server 2008 and a lot of controls. I'm trying to run that app in differente computers that are not connected, i am talking about over 15 computers. What files do i need to copy from my vb app and sql server so it can work in the other computers?

Comment: Not connected? Do you want these machines to share data... use the same database? Or is it okay that each computer has it's own data? If the it's okay, Sql Server 2008 was probably a poor choice. It's meant as a server engine rather than an in-process desktop engine, with server installation and resource requirements. It doesn't deploy as easily and likes to use as many resources as it can get, even when your app is idle or not running. You may want to look into using an in-process engine like Sqlite, Firebird, VistaDB, or even Access.

Comment: For starters, copy the **bin** folder to all the computers and run your app. as sql is involved u may need sql server installed those computers as well

Comment: Great! How do i transfer the databases then? I heard something about doing a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Is the app in Microsoft Access? If so all you have to do is copy that Access Database to all those computers and the SQL Server should just work with those separate copies seamlessly.

We run a few legacy apps in VBA/Access still with SQL Server backends. It's better than most people realize because of how easy it is to modify the only problem is they cant just refresh when you make updates, you have to re-copy the whole Access App to their computer everytime you update it.